# li does not disappear on routing to different html page in Angular, Why?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-routing

I have a page in that I have a table. There is one column named "Actions".

Action-menu is shown with Edit and Delete, once the user clicks on the action-column in any row. I redirect to another html page once the user clicks on edit.

Everything is working fine. But the menu does not disappear after redirecting to another page. If I go back and again click on a action-column, a new menu with edit and delete appears.

```
<p-dataTable #dataTable>
    <p-column field="" header="{{l('Actions')}}" [sortable]="false" [style]="{'width':'25px'}">
        <ng-template let-record="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <div class="btn-group dropdown" normalizePosition>
                <button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-xs btn-primary blue"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a (click)="onEditClick(record, $event)">{{ l('Edit') }}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a (click)="onDeleteClick(record, $event)">{{ l('Delete') }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>

onEditClick(selectedValue: any): void {
   this.router.navigate(['/app/xyz/pqr', selectedClassification.id]);
}
```

Comment: What is the behavior you would like to have? The menu should disappear on routing to another page?

Comment: @MarkusKollers yes ofcourse, it should disappear.

Comment: And you are using plain bootstrap?

Comment: yes, plain bootstarp

Comment: can you replicate this issue in stackblitz will be easy to help

Comment: Could you please try to change `<div class="btn-group dropdown" normalizePosition>` to `<div  dropdown [dropdownToggle]="true" class="btn-group dropdown" normalizePosition>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing angular with plain bootstrap JavaScript. Every time your DropDown gets clicked, the bootstrap-JavaScript creates the menu somewhere at the bottom of your html markup.

angular-router only updates the markup inside of your `router-outlet`, so the attached menu markup will not be removed on navigate.

Try to use a angular specific bootstrap version like this:
 https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples
They should already implemented a solution of your problem, and it will avoid more upcomming issues ;-)

Comment: but the same I'm using on other page, it works fine there

Comment: You are using the same component (drop-down), you are not closing it manually and it disappears on routing?

Comment: Yes,  so where and how do I need to close ?

Comment: How do you navigate in this scenario? With router.navigate(..)? Or with `<a href="...">...</a>` or `window.location`?

Comment: Router.navigate , I have mentioned this in my question

Comment: how does it matter? I'm not redirecting anywhere from second page. Its happening when I'm redirecting from first page to second page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153625/discussion-between-markus-kollers-and-vivek-nuna).